# $[\vec x + \vec y, \vec x + \vec z, \vec y + \vec z]$ = 42, then $[ \vec x, \vec y, \vec z]$=?

Tags: geometry

If
$[\vec x + \vec y, \vec x + \vec z, \vec y + \vec z]$ = 42, 
then $[ \vec x, \vec y, \vec z]$= ?

The correct solution is -21.

I really have no idea where to start, small hint would be helpful...

Answer (score 3):

Since this is determinant, apply opertaions :

> $[\vec x + \vec y ~~~~~ \vec x + \vec z ~~~~~ \vec y + \vec z]$

$1) R_1 \rightarrow R_1-R_3 $

> $[\vec x - \vec z ~~~~~ \vec x + \vec z ~~~~~ \vec y + \vec z]$

$2)  R_1 \rightarrow R_1+R_2 $

> $[2 \vec x  ~~~~~ \vec x + \vec z ~~~~~ \vec y + \vec z]$

$3)$ Take $2$ out of the determinant.

> $2 [ \vec x  ~~~~~ \vec x + \vec z ~~~~~ \vec y + \vec z]$

$4) R_2 \rightarrow R_2  - R_1$

> $2 [ \vec x  ~~~~~ \vec z ~~~~~ \vec y + \vec z]$

$5) R_3 \rightarrow R_3  - R_2$

> $2 [ \vec x  ~~~~~ \vec z ~~~~~ \vec y ]$

$6)$ Interchange $R_2$ and $R_3$

> $ -2 [ \vec x  ~~~~~ \vec y ~~~~~ \vec z ] = [\vec x + \vec y ~~~~~ \vec x + \vec z ~~~~~ \vec y + \vec z]=42 $
>
> $$ \implies  [ \vec x  ~~~~~ \vec y ~~~~~ \vec z ] = -21$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint/Strategy**

Distribute the operations using the definition of the box product. Take advantage of orthogonality (i.e. $a\times a = 0$ and $[a,a,b]=0$). You'll eventually want to take use of the properties of the cross product ($a\times b = -b\times a$) and the cyclic properties of the box product ($[a,b,c]=[b,c,a]=[c,a,b]$).

**Solution**

> \begin{align}
> [x+y,x+z,y+z] &= (x+y)\cdot(x+z)\times(y+z)
> \\
> &= (x+y)\cdot(x\times y+x\times z+z\times y + z\times z)
> \\
> &= x\cdot(x\times y+x\times z+z\times y) + y\cdot(x\times y+x\times z+z\times y)
> \\
> &= x\cdot(z\times y) + y\cdot(x\times z)
> \\
> &= -x\cdot(y\times z) + x\cdot(z\times y)
> \\
> &= -x\cdot(y\times z) - x\cdot(y\times z)
> \\
> &= -2[x,y,z] = 42
> \end{align}

Comment: Can someone edit the solution such that it hides upon scroll over? I forgot how.

Comment: Is the 'box product' common notation? I've never seen it before, it also doesn't seem to cut down on what it is equivalent to - or does it generalise to other things?

Comment: @mrnovice It's really just the determinant of the three-by-three matrix formed from $x+y,x+z,y+z.$. The square-bracket notation isn't terribly common but it's not unheard of.

Comment: @mrnovice Not sure how it generalizes. The term box product refers to the value  $[a,b,c]$ equaling the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by the three vectors. I almost never use the notation; I usually see Levi-Civita and tensor notation $\epsilon_{ijk}a^ib^jc^k$.

Comment: It's not that different, but one can also appeal directly to the triple-product as a determinant. Hence the multilinearity of the determinant gives $$[x+y,x+z,y+z]=[x,x,y]+[x,x,z]+[x,z,y]+[x,z,z]\\+[y,x,y]+[y,x,z]+[y,z,y]+[y,z,z].$$ The antisymmetry of the determinant does the rest. For a generalization, one could have $[x_1+x_2,x_2+x_3,\ldots,x_n+x_1]\propto [x_1,x_2,\ldots x_n]$ where the vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @Semiclassical Oh wow. Of course! You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the matrices $A'=(x+y,x+z,y+z)$, $A=(x,y,z)$ where $x,y,z$ are column 3-vectors. We can write $A'=AM$ by inspection where $$M=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 &0 &1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Since $\det{M}=-2$, we conclude that $\det(A')=-2\det(A)=42\implies \det(A)=-21$. But these determinants coincide with the desired triple products, so we're done.

Comment: Your 'inspection' was very strong !